# How do I actually log in to Stack Exchange/Overflow?

Tags: discussion, login

I login to Stack Exchange.  I see that my reputation has improved and there is a link to an answer that I have provided.  I click that link, and honestly, I think an answer upvoted more than mine is simply inaccurate, so I attempt to downvote it.

And I get a popup saying I should join the community if I want to respond to questions.  On a page that I literally got to from a link on my account page.

Am I doing this wrong?  Is this a bug or intentional?  How many times should anyone need to login to Stack Exchange/Overflow?  I believe that once should be sufficient.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say something like "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 125 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: If you logged in on Stack Exchange you may well not be logged in on Stack Overflow; though they share authentication you can be logged in on one and not another.

Answer (score 2):

You might have logged into the parent website [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/).

Still to log within any of the subdomain sites, e.g. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) you have to agree to authenticate yourself using the same credentials.